# Scanner retornando erro

Tags: java, entrada-de-dados

Estou escrevendo o código abaixo:

```
    public int findNet(String InputRede) {
    try {
        for (GetNetwork network : getRedes()) {
            if (network.getId().equals(InputRede)) {
                return getRedes().indexOf(network);
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException exc) {
        System.out.println("Erro! a interface não é wireless! por favor escolher outra!");
    }
    return -1;
}

public void SelRede() {
    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite a ID da rede");
    idNum = findNet(scanner2.nextLine());
    while (idNum == -1) {
        System.out.println("ID de rede não encontrada! digite novamente!");
        idNum = findNet(scanner2.nextLine());
    }
    System.out.println("Digite a senha da rede (deixe em branco caso não haja)");
    senha = scanner2.nextLine();
    scanner2.close();
}
```

Entretanto, ele tem me retornado o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>     at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
>     at classes.control.SelectNetwork.SelRede(SelectNetwork.java:28)

A linha 28 é esta:

> idNum = findNet(scanner2.nextLine());

Resumidamente, o que está acontecendo é que o código não está executando a scanner, não permitindo ao usuário inserir o texto na variável, retornando o exception NoSuchElementException.

Minha pergunta enão é a seguinte:

Porque o código não está executando executando a scanner?

Comment: Pelo nome da variável, você deve estar usando outro scanner e fechou ele, com este ai ainda aberto. A razão para essa exceção é a mesma da duplicata.

Comment: Obrigado! vou verificar, mas acredito que seja isso mesmo. Essa classe está vinculadas a outra que também trabalha com scanner.